# Regression: can I run specific models or do I need to run a full factorial model?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I am running a GEE (Generalized Estimating Equations) Linear Scale Response regression.
I have 4 IVs: Time pressure and Approach as as factors, and BIS and BAS sensitivity as covariates.
My DV is "Choice".
Under Model tab, I need to specify my model effects.
What I would like to do is to test the main effects for all 4 IVs + the 3-way interaction between Time pressure*Approach*BAS (BIS is included only as a main effect as I want to control for the effect of BIS).
This gives me a significant 3-way interaction effect.
However, I wonder if this is correct? Can I specify the model effects that I am interested in? Don't I need to run full factorial models (that include all possible main, 2-way and 3-way interaction effects)? If I run the full factorial model, the significance of the 3-way interaction disappears.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 3 way interaction, you will (in nearly all cases) want to include the 2 way interactions that are part of that 3 way interaction and all the main effects in the 3 way interaction.

Similarly, if you have a 2 way interaction, you should (in nearly all cases) include the main effects.

You also shouldn't look exclusively at significance; look at effect sizes.

Comment: Thank you Peter! By effect sizes, you mean the B coefficient values?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Look at those and see what they mean in your model.